# error with crawling with nutch

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I was trying to crawl website with nutch and got this error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1265)
            at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:296)
            at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:127)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
            at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your seed list. This error occurred when running injector job. May be due to your seed list. Your seed urls should be as follows: **http://www.example.com** . You must add protocols as "http//" .

Comment: Thanks for your answer,that's work but now i get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1265)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:296)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:127)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
now where is the problem?!

Comment: What are you using for storage (hbase, cassandra or mysql)?  Check your configurations. (as hbase-site.xml ...)

Comment: Examine the Hadoop logs. You can see there is the problem more detail.

Comment: using mysql, u're right i saw logs and the error was because of directory doesn't exist,that's solve.  thanks a lot